# Setting padding on an image and prevent text from flowing outside of parent container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have the following component, it has an image (which should has set width/height) and outer padding of 25px all around.

I'm really struggling however to arrange the markup so that the description text sits below the image (not encroaching the padding) whilst not allowing the text to flow outside of the width of the parent container. Can anyone guide as to where I've gone wrong?

The current snippet shows the description text inside the logo-container padding:

```css
.logoTile {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logoTile .logo-container {
  width: 20.8rem;
  height: 17.4rem;
  padding: 4rem 2.4rem;

}

.logoTile .logo-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.description-text {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="logoTile">
  <div class="logo-container">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/1440/671" loading="eager" alt="Image Alt Text" />
    <p class="description-text">This text should not flow beyond the width of the image (infact should have 16px of padding either side)</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

End goal:

Image that has a width of 20.8rem and height 0f 17.4rem - with 25px on all sides - directly below the image (outside of the padding) should be the description text, it should not be any wider than the image above.

Comment: I can't tell what you actually want here. _"This text should not flow beyond the width of the image"_ - it already doesn't? _"(infact should have 16px of padding either side)"_ - so you want to add `padding: 0 16px` to `.description-text` then, or ... what?

Comment: Add `* { outline: 1px dashed }` to your CSS and you will see that the image pushes the text out of `.logo-container`. Set `img { height: auto }` and it will all fit ( no square image, though!).

Answer (score 0):

With padding this will work, you need to have a base container for the two individual containers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
  .wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  .image-wrapper {
    width:20.8rem;
    height:17.4rem;
    background:#efefef;
    padding:4rem 2.4rem;
    border-radius:4px;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
  }

  .image-wrapper .image {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }

  .image img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
  }

  .wrapper .text {
    width:20.8rem;
    padding:4rem 2.4rem;
    height:200px;
    background:#d3cdcd;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <div class="image">
      <img src="../images/favicon.png">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Saepe tempora accusantium voluptatibus vitae cumque temporibus inventore similique rerum aspernatur ab. Maiores nihil consectetur libero recusandae dolorum consequuntur quas, officiis repellendus.</p>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Image and text.